# How to display contact without company in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

how to display contact without company in odoo 11 , exemple : if **mister X** in **Company Y**, in odoo, display this mister and company : **Y, X**. But i want only **X**. thanks

Comment: Could you please add the Odoo version to your tags? That will help answering this question with code examples, because the "name_get"  approach will result in different code with some versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on debug mode, on contacts list view, go to Debug menu >> Edit list view

[image: Edit List View]

Change from following

```
<tree string="Contacts">
  <field name="display_name" string="Name"/>
  <field name="function" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="phone"/>
  <field name="email"/>
  <field name="user_id" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="is_company" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="country_id" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="parent_id" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="active" invisible="1"/>
</tree>
```

To this

```
<tree string="Contacts">
  <field name="name" string="Name"/>
  <field name="function" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="phone"/>
  <field name="email"/>
  <field name="user_id" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="is_company" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="country_id" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="parent_id" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="active" invisible="1"/>
</tree>
```

This will just change list view name representation for odoo contacts, for Relation fields selection name display, you have to override **`_get_name`**

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
  _inherit='res.partner'

  def _get_name(self):
        """ Utility method to allow name_get to be overrided without re-browse the partner """
        partner = self
        name = partner.name or ''

        if partner.company_name or partner.parent_id:
            if not name and partner.type in ['invoice', 'delivery', 'other']:
                name = dict(self.fields_get(['type'])['type']['selection'])[partner.type]
            #if not partner.is_company:
            #    name = "%s, %s" % (partner.commercial_company_name or partner.parent_id.name, name)
        if self._context.get('show_address_only'):
            name = partner._display_address(without_company=True)
        if self._context.get('show_address'):
            name = name + "\n" + partner._display_address(without_company=True)
        name = name.replace('\n\n', '\n')
        name = name.replace('\n\n', '\n')
        if self._context.get('address_inline'):
            name = name.replace('\n', ', ')
        if self._context.get('show_email') and partner.email:
            name = "%s <%s>" % (name, partner.email)
        if self._context.get('html_format'):
            name = name.replace('\n', '<br/>')
        if self._context.get('show_vat') and partner.vat:
            name = "%s ‒ %s" % (name, partner.vat)
        return name
```

Comment: Changing the list view in debug mode or technical settings is not permanent. Why not creating a custom module for permanent changes?

Answer (score 2):

That name comes via name_get method written inside res.partner.py You need to extend that method in your custom module and remove company name as a prefix from the contact name.